# Change mouse right button events type to onmouseclick

Tags: linux, mouse, fedora, nautilus, fedora-17

I have noticed that in Fedora almost all events related to mouse right button are of onmousepress type, e.g. as soon as I press the mouse right button (but not released yet), it shows the context menu in nautilus. This is really weird because in Windows the context menu is not shown until I release the mouse button. In some situations this even makes some problems, for example some times when I try to right click, it automatically creates a new folder ("create new folder" is the first entry in my context menu).

Is there any way to change the type of mouse right button events to onmouseclick?